# python speech recognition in Tkinter

Tags: python, loops, tkinter, speech-recognition

I have a code,which will display the text from speech recognition to the text box.

Problem: It just listen **once** then stops running.I need to `listen it till,i close the Tkinter`.

If i say **clear** then It has to clear the contents on the textbox.
My problem is,I cannot tell the contents to the Tkinter directly.It listens after the Shell outputs.

Please help me to solve my problem.

Coding:

```
from Tkinter import *
import pyaudio
import tkMessageBox
import Tkinter as tki
import tkFileDialog as th1
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    audio = r.listen(source) 
try:
    a=(r.recognize(audio))
    print a
except LookupError:                            
    a=("Could not understand audio")
    print a
class App(object):

    def __init__(self,root):
        self.root = root

    # create a Frame for the Text and Scrollbar
        txt_frm = tki.Frame(self.root, width=900, height=900)
        txt_frm.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        # ensure a consistent GUI size
        txt_frm.grid_propagate(False)

    # create first Text label, widget and scrollbar
        self.lbl1 = tki.Label(txt_frm, text="Type")
        self.lbl1.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=2,pady=2)

        self.txt1 = tki.Text(txt_frm, borderwidth=3, relief="sunken", height=4,width=55)
        self.txt1.config(font=("consolas", 12), undo=True, wrap='word')
        self.txt1.grid(row=25, column=7, sticky="nsew", padx=2, pady=2)
        self.txt1.insert(0.0,a)

    def clearBox(self):
        if a == "clear":
            self.txt1.delete('1.0', 'end')        
root = tki.Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You need threading to solve this, and because Tkinter doesn't know about threading, you need the after-function to poll for changes/recognitions in your mainloop.

Comment: @deets could you help me with an small example,involving my query?

Comment: @sarkite: If you've got PyAudio to work with speech_recognition, as it seems you've done here, could you please either close, or better, answer, your other question about it.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26666216/pyaudio-build-and-install-python-portaudio-bindings-first

Comment: On a totally unrelated topics.. Could you tell me how you got speech_recognition to work? I keep getting `no module named speech_recognition`

Comment: you should install with this command (Look CamelCase letters )   pip install SpeechRecognition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use threading to run a proper concurrent speech-recognition, and update the text-widgets contents using the after-method, because Tkinter doesn't support threading in a different manner.

I don't have speech-recognition working here, so you need to fill in the blanks and replace the random.choice-call with your actual speech-recognition.

```
 import threading
 import time
 import random

 from Tkinter import *
 import tkMessageBox
 import Tkinter as tki
 import tkFileDialog as th1

 class SpeechRecognizer(threading.Thread):

     ANSWERS = ["foo", "bar"]

     def __init__(self):
         super(SpeechRecognizer, self).__init__()
         self.setDaemon(True)
         self.recognized_text = "initial"

     def run(self):
         while True:
             time.sleep(1.0)
             self.recognized_text = random.choice(self.ANSWERS)


 recognizer = SpeechRecognizer()
 recognizer.start()

 class App(object):

     def __init__(self,root):
         self.root = root

     # create a Frame for the Text and Scrollbar
         txt_frm = tki.Frame(self.root, width=900, height=900)
         txt_frm.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
         # ensure a consistent GUI size
         txt_frm.grid_propagate(False)

     # create first Text label, widget and scrollbar
         self.lbl1 = tki.Label(txt_frm, text="Type")
         self.lbl1.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=2,pady=2)

         self.recognized_text = StringVar()
         self.txt1 = tki.Text(txt_frm, borderwidth=3, relief="sunken", height=4,width=55,
         )
         self.txt1.config(font=("consolas", 12), undo=True, wrap='word')
         self.txt1.grid(row=25, column=7, sticky="nsew", padx=2, pady=2)
         root.after(100, self.update_recognized_text)

     def update_recognized_text(self):
         self.txt1.delete(0.0, END)
         self.txt1.insert(0.0, recognizer.recognized_text)
         root.after(100, self.update_recognized_text)

     def clearBox(self):
         if a == "clear":
             self.txt1.delete('1.0', 'end')

 root = tki.Tk()
 app = App(root)
 root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I performed the above execution and edited random with my speech recognition as sgown here http://pastebin.com/7Czqq1Pr  But,I can speak only once,then it not recognizes and prints, and works as same as my previous coding.Please help me to make some changes,so that I could able to speak,till I close my Tkinter.And I doesnot recognize `clear`

Comment: You have to put your speech-recognition code *inside* the run-method of the Thread-subclass, not just assign the once computed value over and over.

Comment: I have posted a new question,regarding this issue,completely. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26731763/tkinter-to-display-and-clear-text-from-speech-recognition  Could u please help me with this.

Comment: I can't, because those questions pertain to the actual speech recognition - something I haven't available & no prior know-how of. good luck!